# WPF how to preserve themes in a custom control

Tags: wpf, button, custom-controls

How can i Create a reusable custom button with image and Text like this :

[image]

and when I use it in a window it must respect the theme used in that window.

Currently i use the following code :

```
<Button x:Name="cmdSave" Margin="5" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"    ToolTip="Save...">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="..\images\icons\yellowfloppy.ico" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Enregistrer" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{StaticResource GreenForeGroundTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
```

The problem is i have to repeat the previous code each time i want to display a custom button.

So I tried the following custom control :

```
 public class MyButton : Button
{


    public ImageSource ImageButton
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageButtonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageButtonProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageButton.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageButton", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MyButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



    public string TextButton
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextButtonProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextButtonProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TextButton.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextButtonProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextButton", typeof(string), typeof(MyButton), new PropertyMetadata(""));


    static MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
    }
}
```

and in Generic.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyButton">
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyButton}">
                <Border CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="2">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageButton, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding TextButton}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and here the test window :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfmyButtonTest.MainWindow"
     xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyButton;assembly=MyButton"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ShinyBlue.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <b:MyButton ImageButton="commercial.png" TextButton="Test"  Margin="274,225,40,40"/>
</Grid>
```

But this code doesn't display what i expect, so All behavior of a normal button disappeared and the ShinyBlue theme is not applied.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer to this question. See link [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knom/archive/2007/10/31/wpf-control-development-3-ways-to-build-an-imagebutton.aspx).
In fact, it is sufficient to incorporate a button inside a usercontrol like this :

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Knom.WPF.ImageButton.ImageButton2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Name="UC">
<Grid>
    <Button>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
            <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=Image}"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=ImageWidth}"
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=ImageHeight}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=UC, Path=Text}"
                       Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
          </StackPanel>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

   namespace Knom.WPF.ImageButton
    {
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ImageButton2.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ImageButton2 : UserControl
{
    public ImageButton2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Image.  This enables    animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton2), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public double ImageWidth
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ImageWidthProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageWidthProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageWidth.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageWidth", typeof(double), typeof(ImageButton2), new UIPropertyMetadata(16d));

    public double ImageHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ImageHeight.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageHeight", typeof(double), typeof(ImageButton2), new UIPropertyMetadata(16d));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(ImageButton2), new UIPropertyMetadata(""));

//This is for MVVM Command
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ImageButton2), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

}

i can use it like this :

```
<Window x:Class="Knom.WPF.ImageButton.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Knom.WPF.ImageButton">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="BureauBlue.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

    <my:ImageButton2 Image="calendar.png" Text="UserControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    ImageWidth="16" ImageHeight="16" Margin="10" Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>

</Window>
```

And it is reusable and works fine

Thank you